# Can we fetch the iOS system ringtone in iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

I want to use the system phone ringtone which user has set into my app. Is it possible to do that?

Currently, I have added a ringtone file in my app and successfully playing that ringtone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**I am sorry to say but is not possible.**

You cannot. Apple doesn't release an API Or SDK to export/write ringtones to the operating system.